# SwiftUI: How to know when view is moved inside scroll view?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I need some direction to resolve a problem. I have multiple videos inside a scroll view and I want only one of them to play at a time. I know about geo.frame to know the position of the view in screen but how can I constantly check if the screen moved to a point? I want to use this code in the video player view but I can only put this to .onAppear and it won't work because it is only called once. Is there a method that I can check when the screen is moved (scroll view is dragged) so that I can play the video in the middle and stop the other ones?

```
if (geo.frame(in: .global).midY > 200 && geo.frame(in: .global).midY < 800) {
                                avPlayer.play()
                                print("Global center: \(geo.frame(in: .global).midX) x \(geo.frame(in: .global).midY)")
                                print("Video to play: \(postID)")
                            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code inside your view body using the Geometry reader. The value of geo is updated as the items are being scrolled and moved around.
Put this in a view of a row in your table of videos:

```
struct Example: View {

    private func checkLocation(geo: GeometryProxy) -> Bool {
        let loc = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
        print ("Loc is: \(loc)")
        if loc > 200 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if checkLocation(geo: geo) {
                Text ("This is working")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guy but I recieve "Type () cannot conform to View" error in the if line.

Comment: My bad, we cannot use if directly in view body, but it should work inside groups. I thought that GeometryReader would be enough, apparently not.  Try to put the "if" inside a group() { ... 
}.  It can also work inside HStack(), VStack(), ZStack().  I will fix my answer if that works for you

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is geo.frame() is a method so it won't work. Otherwise an if with a simple bool would work.

Comment: I am copying the code that I checked and it is working well with my tests. Notice that I used a private function inside the View, maybe this makes the difference, but I liked doing it for simplicity anyway, it makes the logic inside the "body" easier to follow. Also notice that the use of Group is not required, the GeometryReader is good enough . I hope this example will be good for you.